# How do Devs share relevant testing information with Devs-in-Test and QAs?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tdd, manual-testing

One of the problems our group is having is in regards to sharing relevant information between the Devs, Devs in Test and QAs.

How is this typically done in the industry?

For instance, our devs typically follow TDD with CI/CD pipelines offering the capability to illustrate code coverage. Do devs in test and QAs typically review coverage numbers prior to construction of integration and manual test plans?

How are devs typically communicating edge cases and relevant test procedures to the testers these days?

Finally are there any great resources (docs, podcasts etc) that discuss these types of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, there isn't a whole lot of such information shared between DEV and QA, apart from the requirements, things like API documentation and maybe usage examples. The reason is simple: Developer tests (unit, integration) are usually whilebox tests, while tests performed by QA are usually blackbox tests (i.e. oblivious of the code being tested). What use is a coverage report for blackbox tests?

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Considering unit/integration tests as whitebox vs the QAs blackbox test is a good analogy and that's more or less the situation we're in.

Comment: Perhaps the key piece I'm missing is the collaboration that happens between the QAs and Devs/Dev in test in regard to Quality as a whole - from unit testing to CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

What i think in this case is , If we use tools like JIRA, then in each story/ticket on which Dev is working he/she should mention all the related doc, details and major technical specifications like which module/API/project_layer he has worked on to solve this particular requirement with atleast few of his unit test links to this ticket will certainly help while testing.
And this thing also helps in accounting of code changes done in the project for the tickets so that we can also guess the major regression areas.
Let me know if u find this helpful.
Thanks